# Android App deployed to playstore does not auto update

Tags: android, google-play, auto-update

I have deployed an Android app as an Alpha release on the playstore. I downloaded the app to my Nexus 5 phone running Android 5.0. When I pushed a new build to the playstore, the app on the phone does not auto update. The app has been configured to auto update and when I pushed an update to the playstore, the playstore settings for "my apps" on the phone does show a new version being available but it does not "auto update" unless I manually update it. I have waited more than 24 hrs to see if it eventually updates but have had no luck.

Any clues on what I am missing?

Comment: I finally got this working by restarting the device.  Wondering if this is the expected behavior of the updates being applied only on reboot?

Answer (score -1):

Did you update the `versionCode` in your manifest?
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html

Comment: Gooplay console does't let you delploy a new apk with an existing version code

Comment: Buddy - like Giorgos mentioned, the app console does not allow publishing a new release unless the version code has been incremented. Also since the app does show up in the list of apps available to be updated under "my apps" means Android recoginzes the update but fails to auto update.

Comment: Does your new version require additional permissions?

Comment: I also noticed that it is not only my app that fails to auto-update, there are other apps like Google Maps, Google Play Music ... which appear in the list of apps with updates available and are set to "auto update" but have not yet been updated.

Comment: Buddy - nope - the app is identical as the one installed on the phone with the exception of the changes made to manifest file & build.gradle to update the version code.